# Using regular expression to remove text?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here's a copy of some of the lines in my txt file:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
```

Is there a way in NotePad++ to use regular expression to remove everything except the `City` in each line?

Answer (score 2):

Find:

```
^[^,]+,([^,]+).+$
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

Explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cLCGky1lzJGDAtxE)

I have tested this on your data, and it works correctly.